# Support Vector Machine in Apache Spark

Tags: machine-learning, svm, apache-spark

I would like to have some insights in running **Support Vector Machine (SVM)** in [Apache Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/).
When I use the *run-example* script given in the Spark home directory and using the argument `org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD` it displays the following `Usage: SVM <master> <input_dir> <step_size> <regularization_parameter> <niters>` message. I understand the *`<master>`*, the *`<input_dir>`* and the *`<niters>`* arguments.
Can you please help me figure out the rest of the arguments or at least direct me to some tutorial site of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<step_size>` is the starting point for the learning rate. For convergence the step-size should be decreasing. In SGD this is implemented by taking the input value for `step_size` and dividing by the square root of the iteration.

`<reg_param>`is the scalar adjusting the strength of the constraints. Small values imply a soft margin and large values imply a hard margin. Infinity is the hardest margin.

Answer (score 2):

[They are explained in the docs in the last section.](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html)